# with bootstrap navbar on mobile & ipad

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

I've been trying to get my site to work on mobile and iphone 5 (works fine on iphone 6). it works on the emulator but on the server it doesn't. I'm getting a margin of some 20px to my right.

[it works fine on the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Acb.jpg) : [anandandakhil.me](http://www.anandandakhil.me)

I looked up some threads here on stackoverflow but they didnt work.

one of them was `@media(max-width:768px)`

i tried attaching  it to the class navbar , navbar-collapse

here's the code

### index.html

Toggle navigation

Home

About

Portfolio

Get in Touch

### style.css

```
#navbar-header.navbar-default {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #f28500;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #f28500;
    background-color: #fff;
}
@media(max-width:768px) {
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #f28500;
}
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #f28500;
}
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#navbar-header.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #f28500;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Bootstrap as well.

As far as I know, the screen resolution of a mobile phone is different than its css resolution. For example iPhone 5 has a screen resolution of 640x1136, but the css resolution is 320x568.

Comment: how do i make it appear properly?